# ChromeOption is not working with Selenium-Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the above code with selenium-java version 4.0.0, selenium-server version 3.11.0, webdrivermanager version 5.0.3 .

Still chrome is not launching in maximised screen and not disbaling the infobars as well.

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class chromeOptionsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I am running this test on macbook m1.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not setup `WebDriverManager` in my `pom.xml` file and used this `chromrdriver.exe` file instead:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\panabh02\\OneDrive - CSG Systems Inc\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
```

this did work for me.

Also, you can try with this options with `--` and

```
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920, 1080");
```

like below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\***\\****\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920, 1080");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximizing window on Mac was unstable (works for some cases, and doesn't work for others) and a lot of people mentioned this.

This one is closed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2522

But this still in opened
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=868599

This might not work:

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

or

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

---

**Workarounds**

1 Start in full-screen:

```
options.addArguments("start-fullscreen");
```

2 Resize window (it's less flexible, because need to know screen size):

after driver launched

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0))
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080))
```

or with option

```
options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
```

---

P.S.

Your code

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

means that you not using `selenium-server`, but use the local chrome driver. But this should not be related to the issue.

---

Answer (score 0):

To setup a chrome driver to full screen, you can use this method

```
public static void setDriver() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

no matter what your screen resolution is, the window will be full screen